# Table view separators not expanded in split view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, ios9

Is there a fix for this in iOS 9?  The table view separators don't resize automatically now when expanding a split view controller.

[image]

The table view separators are not resized here in iOS 9 when expanding the detail view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and this is expected behavior in iOS 9 which is different from iOS 8.  To get the same behavior as in iOS 8 you use the new `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth` property.

```
self.tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
```